# How to send an embed in a webhook using only discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Well the case is that I want to send an embed in a webhook. But this one gives me an answer in the webhook channel: `<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000000E32CFC9820>` But in a preview of it (sending it through my bot) the same thing does not happen

Embed:

```
embed = discord.Embed(
    title = 'Test'
    )
embed.add_field(name='Field name', value='asd')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`discord.Webhook`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Webhook):

```
from discord import Webhook, AsyncWebhookAdapter
import aiohttp

@client.command()
async def send_webhook(ctx):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        webhook = Webhook.from_url('webhook_url', adapter=AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))

        e = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Description")
        e.add_field(name="Field 1", value="Value 1")
        e.add_field(name="Field 2", value="Value 2")

        await webhook.send(embed=e)
```

Comment: discord.py has built in webhook stuff i dont see the need for an external lib for this https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#webhook-support

Comment: I'm aware of that, that is just the library that I use. I will include a discord.py example.